# What is/are the synonym/s for 'to move to sit closer to someone'?

Tags: verbs, synonyms, phrasal-verbs, north-american-english

I have a couple of things in mind, but I'm not sure if they can be applied to **sitting** position.

For example, if I'm sitting on the other end of the couch, and then I move to sit closer to someone else, then I ______ closer.

Things I thought of were *shuffle*, *huddle*, *snuggle*. Are they all correct in this particular situation? Are there any other possible variants?

There's also a phrasal verb on the tip of my tongue, "______ up".

Thanks!

Comment: You could *slide* or *shift* or *scoot* closer...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe coming closer (together) or getting closer could be, but definitely, it does not imply being sitting, then you must point out the situation. 
For example:

> "While we were watching the movie we got closer, or I got closer to him/her".

Although, it is certain these phrasal verbs could have a figurative meaning which in the former example could mean gaining intimacy or knowing each another better.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, there's ***[scoot over](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scoot_over)*** and ***[scooch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scooch)***.

*Shuffle* and *huddle* are appropriate, the distinction being that one person might *shuffle* towards another stationary person, whereas two or more people might *huddle* together. *Snuggle* probably suggests more intimacy than you intend.

Comment: For some reason I always thought 'scoot over' meant the opposite of 'move closer' (like 'move away' or 'make some place'). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Phrasal verb/ idiomatic expression.

**[sidle up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sidle+up)** (to someone or something)
<sup>TFD citing McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.</sup>

> to move close to someone or something cautiously or furtively; to move closer to someone or something gradually.
>   *Tex sidled up to Dolly and said howdy in a soft, shy voice.
>
>   Dolly sidled up and picked the cowboy's pocket.*

Deborah Smith, "Jed's Sweet Revenge," [GoogleBooks](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=d-7HHYk4T5sC&pg=PT50&dq=%22sidle%20up%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi35Yq2vLjgAhUHabwKHSI_ByoQ6AEIigEwEA#v=onepage&q=%22sidle%20up%20to%22&f=false):

> Now, if she were Marlene Dietrich in *Destry Rides Again*, she'd **sidle up to** Jed and purr, "Vee oughta be friends, you know, mister. Good friends." And he'd do anything she wanted. (emphasis mine)

Answer (score -1):

The phrasal you are thinking about could be [hutch up](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hutch_up). This is described as an idomatic phrase meaning

> To move slightly (sideways), in order to make room for someone; for example to move in a bed to make room for someone else to lie, or to move sideways on on a seat so as to allow someone room to sit and share that same seat.

Although it is defined as moving over to make room for someone it often involves two or more people moving closer together on a seat in order to create the space as in "Hutch up you two, make room for a little one." The phrase *is* idiomatic rather than formal English and is not often used with strangers, its use does, usually, imply some degree of intimacy with the person or people addressed. I'm British and I accept that "hutch up" may not be used for "move over" the US but it may still be the phrase you're looking for.

According to the Wikipedia page "hutch up" can also mean to share a home with someone so that the rent is more affordable and to put on a more heterosexual attitude to be more socially acceptable but its "move over" meaning is much more familiar to me and is, I suspect, the original.